# Web scraper returns NoneType object for certain articles

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Logical flow of the scraper: article links extracted from an XML feed are put into a list called self.raw_html. The following [simplified] method is then called to filter out the container the articles are in and remove text from the given articles:

```
def fetch_article_contents(self):
    for article in self.raw_html:
        self.css_selector_type == 'class':
        soup = article.find(self.html_element,
                            self.css_selector)
        soup = soup.get_text()
        self.article_html.append(soup)
    return self.article_html
```

This works well on most feeds, but on two notable exemptions (Forbes and Official Google Blog) fails with the following message when get_text() is called:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

My first logical step in debugging was to see what was returning a NoneType object, so I stuck a `print type(soup)` right before `soup = soup.get_text()`. I found:

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> (25 times, condensed to save space)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

This also strikes me as strange because there are currently 29 articles in `self.raw_html` when fetching the Forbes XML feed as verified by len(self.raw_html) when the class is initalized.

The Google Official Blog returns:

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> (just once this time)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

and in reality has 25 fetched articles.

What is the problem I'm encountering? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show what `self.html_element` and `self.css_selector` are, but it seems clear the the `article.find` method is not finding them, and returning `None`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that into the OP. self.html_element and self.css_selector are parameters passed to the class that tell the scraper what HTML element and class to take out. It can't be this, because the method does a number of articles successfully (shown by <class 'bs4.element.Tag'> before returning NoneType and stopping.

Comment: You assume that all the articles are the same, and that they all have the element you are searching for.

Comment: Aah, that does make sense. Thanks; I'll report back with results later. :)

Comment: Used a try/except statement to try and figure out some more details, and I came up with some interesting realizations: when I filter out things returning NoneType on the Forbes side, I get the correct, full number of articles. On the Google side, you were right in that parts of the html were missing, which confuses me even more, but that's a question best reserved for another post. ;) Thanks a lot for your help.